# Attaching IAM user to IAM Group using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM policy, to an IAM group using Boto3. So far, I am not able to add IAM user to an IAM group. For "response = iam.add_user_to_group( ", I am getting an error, "Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'iam.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'add_user_to_group'"

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.resource('iam') #using resource representing IAM
created_user = iam.create_user(
    UserName='some_random_user'
)
print(created_user)

create_group_response = iam.create_group(GroupName = 'Tester')

response = iam.add_user_to_group(
UserName = 'some_random_user', #Name of user
GroupName = 'Tester'
)

response = iam.attach_user_policy(
UserName = 'some_random_user', #Name of user
PolicyArn = 'arn:aws:iam::196687784845:policy/boto-test' 
# Policy ARN which you want to asign to user
)
```

Not sure what seems to be the problem, I am very new to python and boto so might be a very small thing.

Comment: `create_group_response.add_user(UserName='some_random_user')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#client), `add_user_to_group` is an action for IAM **client** (not resource). Use [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Group.add_user) action on Group resource instead.

Comment: so you mean instead of "iam.add_user_to_group (" I should use "iam.add_user (" . If that is what you were implying that does not seem to work as well

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Please see jordanm's comment above.